# How to use tail.select in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tail.select

I am relatively new in VueJS. I am having trouble in using tail.select plugin in vueJS

I am done importing the plugin on my main.js `import 'tail.select'`

but upon calling the `tail.select(".select")` on my `mounted` it gives me an error that says `Uncaught ReferenceError: tail is not defined`.

HTML

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-sm select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Script

```js
export default {
  mounted(){
    flatpickr('.datepicker',{
      altFormat: "F j, Y",
      dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    })
    tail.select(".select")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that an actual runtime error or does it come from ESLint? Does it happen to have something like `[no-undef]` at the end of the message?

Comment: @Phil there is no `[no-undef]`. It is an actual runtime error the exact message is `Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: tail is not defined"`

Comment: I would like to note a change for the `tail.select` library. The old repository is gone completely and the new version is here -

https://github.com/wolffe/tail.select.js

Also, the demo is available here -

https://getbutterfly.com/tail-select/

Since the plugin has disappeared, a few months ago, I have updated it to version 0.5.20 and an ES6 version 0.6 is in the works. I am maintaining this plugin/library full time.

Answer (score 0):

[Tail.Select](https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/wiki/public-methods#reload) has prototype method called reload that contains this function:

```
        /*
         |  PUBLIC :: RELOAD SELECT
         |  @since  0.5.0 [0.3.0]
         */
        reload: function(){
            return this.remove().init();
        },
```

Which basically calls `remove()` and `init()`, which results in re-populating the data into:

`div.tail-select.no-classes.deselect` which is the container of tail.select in HTML document.

To use it with [Vue JS](https://vuejs.org/) apply the reload method in `Vue updated method` to a new instance of `Tail.Select` like this example, where `document.querySelectorAll` is used to target all `select` input in HTML document based on unique class name `js-select`:

> This function activates tail.select

```
/**
* Activates Tail.select third party library for select options
*/
function activateTailSelect() {
    var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.js-select');
    var options = {
        deselect: true,
        search: true,
        width: "100%",
        openAbove: false
    };
    if (sel.length > 0) {
        sel.forEach(function (s) {
            var tSelect = tail.select(s, options);
            tSelect.reload(true);
        });
    }
}
```

> Calling previous function on Vue update event

```
// Vue App Instance
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: { 
          message: "Vue loaded"
        },
        updated() {
        // this phase is after re-render virtual DOM and patch and before destroy
        activateTailSelect();

        }
    });
```